# Mismatch in .NET metadata for SQL DateTime2 type

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm getting a thrown exception when attempting to import a `SqlDataRecord` with a `DateTime2` data type. There is no exception thrown in this snippet, but the cause of the later exception is evident in the following code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Testing123
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static object SQLTParser(SqlMetaData smd, string val)
        {
            TypeCode systc = Parameter.ConvertDbTypeToTypeCode(smd.DbType);

            try
            {
                return Convert.ChangeType(val, systc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is InvalidCastException || ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception reached casting " + val + " to " + Type.GetType("System." + Enum.GetName(typeof(TypeCode), systc)) + ": " + ex.Message + ex.ToString()); //smd.GetType().Name 
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Null value exception");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            SqlMetaData sqmd = new SqlMetaData("dt", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 27, 7);
            SqlDataRecord sdr = new SqlDataRecord(sqmd);
            sdr.SetValue(0, SQLTParser(sqmd, "2017-01-12 01:23:12.3456789"));
            //set BreakPoint
            //sdr -> Non-Public members -> _columnMetaData[0] -> Precision = 27
            //sdr -> Non-Public members -> _columnSmiMetaData[0] -> Non-Public members -> Precision = 0
        }
    }
}
```

As noted, if you set the breakpoint and watches as indicated in MS Visual Studio*, Precision does not match between columnMetaData and columnSmiMetaData, which by the second such entry (!!) throws an exception:

> Metadata for field 'dt' of record '2' did not match the original record's metadata.

which matches the exception thrown by

[line 3755 of ValueUtilsSmi](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/Microsoft/SqlServer/Server/ValueUtilsSmi.cs,3754)

due to the return of [MetadataUtilsSmi.IsCompatible](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/Microsoft/SqlServer/Server/MetadataUtilsSmi.cs,8e62ce86f0e03d27)

Essentially, precision in the field's metadata of record 2 doesn't match that which is in the `SmiMetaData` of record 1. In record 1, the MD and SMD don't match either, but based on the logic Microsoft was using for an `IEnumerator`'d `SqlDataRecord`, it doesn't become an issue until the 2nd record.

Is this a MS bug? Or is there a way to force the precision value of the `SmiMetaData`? Or ignore that particular field check in `ValueUtilsSmi`? Specifying `SqlMetaData sqmd = new SqlMetaData("dt", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 0, 7);` allows the parsing to proceed, but drops sub-second precision from the data.

Here is, in a nutshell, how I'm attempting to send the data to a database. Apologies if this portion is not a complete example.

```
public class FullStreamingDataRecord : IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    private string _filePath;
    public bool _hasHeader { get; private set; }
    private ParserDict _pd; //notably has colStructure which is an array of SqlMetaData[]

    public FullStreamingDataRecord(string FilePath, ParserDict pd)
    {
        _filePath = FilePath;
        _pd = pd;
        _hasHeader = true;
    }

    public static object SQLTParser(SqlMetaData smd, string val)
    {
        TypeCode systc = Parameter.ConvertDbTypeToTypeCode(smd.DbType);

        try
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(val, systc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is InvalidCastException || ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception reached casting " + val + " to " + Type.GetType("System."+Enum.GetName(typeof(TypeCode),systc)) + ": " + ex.Message + ex.ToString()); //smd.GetType().Name 
                return null; //smd.TParse(val);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Null value exception casting...attempting a different method");
                return null; smd.TParse(val);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int len = this._pd.colStructure.Length;
        StreamReader fileReader = null;

        try
        {
            using (fileReader = new StreamReader(this._filePath))
            {
                string inputRow = "";
                string[] inputColumns = new string[len];

                if (_hasHeader && !fileReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    inputRow = fileReader.ReadLine(); //and ignore
                }

                while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
                { 
                    string temp = "";
                    inputRow = fileReader.ReadLine();
                    inputColumns = inputRow.Split(new char[]{','},len);
                    SqlDataRecord dataRecord = this._pd.colStructure

                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) { // i = counter for input columns
                        string currentKey = this._pd.colStructure[j].SqlMetaData.Name;
                        string curval = inputColumns[j];
                        var ty = this._pd.colStructure[j].SqlMetaData; //.DbType;
                        dataRecord.SetValue(j, SQLTParser(ty, curval));
                        // dataRecord.GetSqlMetaData(j).Adjust(dataRecord.GetValue(j));
                    }

                    yield return dataRecord;
                }
            }
        }
        // no catch block allowed due to the "yield" command
        finally 
        {
            fileReader.Close();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Which I call with this in my Main()

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new DBConnect().conn)
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand importProc = new SqlCommand("tvp_"+pd.tableDestination, conn);
    importProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    importProc.CommandTimeout = 300;

    SqlParameter importTable = new SqlParameter();
    importTable.ParameterName = "@ImportTable";
    importTable.TypeName = "dbo.tt_"+pd.tableDestination;
    importTable.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    importTable.Value = new FullStreamingDataRecord(fn, pd);
    importProc.Parameters.Add(importTable);

    importProc.ExecuteNonQuery(); //this line throws the exception
}
```

Apologies for not `Console.WriteLine`ing the values of these watches.

Unfortunately, it seems that these parameters are protected against examination using Reflection's sdr.GetType().GetProperties(), even with the appropriate BindingFlags set. But at least you can see the values in debug mode!

Comment: I suspect the answer may be in part influenced by DataTypeCompatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652681/4228193